# get error on "buildozer android debug deploy run"

Tags: android, kivy

get this error

## Command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy"

when trying to 
$ buildozer android debug deploy run

How to fix it?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means something went wrong in the python-for-android build step, but there are tons of problems that would give that error.

Could you set the buildozer token `log_level = 2` in your buildozer.spec and try it again (by default it will be `1`). This will get buildozer to print much more information about the build process, including hopefully more about the error. Then, could you include that error information here?